# How to use the system spell checker dictionary in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, spell-checking, hunspell

I want to maintain one good dictionary system wide. Unfortunately there are many applications which use their own Hunspell dictionary.
Finally it depends on the application and its outdated dictionaries, if typos in a text were found or not.

How can I let my **Firefox** use the **system wide Hunspell dictionaries** and the personal dictionary?